# Removing entire row if there are repetitive values in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have read **a CSV file** (that have name and addresses of customers)  and assign the data into DataFrame table.

**Description of the csv file (or the DataFrame table)**

DataFrame contains several rows and 7 columns

**Database example**

```py
Client_id Client_Name Address1        Address3       Post_Code   City_Name              Full_Address                            

 C0000001     A       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535      MERSCH       37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH     
 C0000001     A       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535      MERSCH       37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH     
 C0000001     A       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535      MERSCH       37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH     
 C0000002     B       10001998  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN    L-1855  LUXEMBOURG  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG     
 C0000002     B       10001998  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN    L-1855  LUXEMBOURG  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG     
 C0000002     B       10001998  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN    L-1855  LUXEMBOURG  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG     
 C0000003     C       11000051       9 RUE DU BRILL    L-3898       FOETZ           9 RUE DU BRILL,L-3898 ,FOETZ     
 C0000003     C       11000051       9 RUE DU BRILL    L-3898       FOETZ           9 RUE DU BRILL,L-3898 ,FOETZ     
 C0000003     C       11000051       9 RUE DU BRILL    L-3898       FOETZ           9 RUE DU BRILL,L-3898 ,FOETZ     
 C0000004     D       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535      MERSCH       37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH     
 C0000005     E       10001998  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN    L-1855  LUXEMBOURG  RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG
```

**So far I have written this code to generate the aformentioned table :**

**The code is**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
Excel_file = 'Address.xlsx'
Address_Info = pd.read_excel(Excel_file)

# rename the columns name
Address_Info.columns = ['Client_ID', 'Client_Name','Address_ID','Street_Name','Post_Code','City_Name','Country'] 

# extract specfic columns into a new dataframe
Bin_Address= Address_Info[['Client_Name','Address_ID','Street_Name','Post_Code','City_Name','Country']].copy()


# Clean existing whitespace from the ends of the strings
Bin_Address= Bin_Address.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip(), axis=1)  # ← added

# Adding a new column called (Full_Address) that concatenate address columns into one 
# for example   Karlaplan 13,115 20,STOCKHOLM,Stockholms län, Sweden
Bin_Address['Full_Address'] = Bin_Address[Bin_Address.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)

Bin_Address['Full_Address']=Bin_Address[['Full_Address']].copy()


Bin_Address['latitude'] = 'None'
Bin_Address['longitude'] = 'None'

# Remove repetitive addresses
#Temp = list( dict.fromkeys(Bin_Address.Full_Address) )

# Remove repetitive values ( I do beleive the modification should be here)
Temp = list( dict.fromkeys(Address_Info.Client_ID) )
```

I am looking to remove **the entire row** if there are repetitive values in the  **Client id, Client name , and  Full_Address** columns,  so far code doesnt show any error but at the same time, I havnt got the expected out ( i do beleive the modification would be in the last line of the attached code)

**The expected output is**

```py
Client_id Client_Name Address1        Address3       Post_Code   City_Name              Full_Address                            
 C0000001     A       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535     MERSCH           37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH            
 C0000002     B       10001998    RUE EDWARD STEICHEN  L-1855     LUXEMBOURG       RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG         
 C0000003     C       11000051    9 RUE DU BRILL       L-3898     FOETZ            9 RUE DU BRILL,L-3898 ,FOETZ         
 C0000004     D       10000009    37 RUE DE LA GARE    L-7535     MERSCH           37 RUE DE LA GARE,L-7535, MERSCH     
 C0000005     E       10001998    RUE EDWARD STEICHEN  L-1855     LUXEMBOURG       RUE EDWARD STEICHEN,L-1855,LUXEMBOURG
```

Comment: can you try `<your_dataframe>.drop_duplicates(subset=["Client_id", "Client_name" , "Full_Address"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built in method called `dorp_duplicates()` from pandas. Also there is lot of options out of the box you can apply.

```
<your_dataframe>.drop_duplicates(subset=["Client_id", "Client_name", "Full_Address"])
```

You also have options for when it is duplicate, if you want to keep the first value or last value.

```
  <your_dataframe>.drop_duplicates(subset=["Client_id", "Client_name", "Full_Address"], keep="first") # "first" or "last"
```

By default it will always keep the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Client id', 'Client name', 'Full_Address'])
```